# Making php-mode (and other cc-mode derived modes) compatible with Emacs 23

Tags: emacs, php-mode, cc-mode

I am using Emacs 23 and [php-mode.el](http://php-mode.sourceforge.net/) 1.5.0. When I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'php-mode)
```

I get this error message when Emacs starts:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/kdj/.emacs':
>
> error: `c-lang-defconst' must be used in a file
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
>   the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

If I evaluate `(require 'php-mode)` after Emacs starts, I don't get any error messages.

I found a [blog entry](http://atomized.org/2008/12/php-mode-150-is-out/) which indicates that this problem is specific to Emacs 23 (that is, there is no error with Emacs 22.x), but it doesn't give any solutions.

I don't know if this matters, but I'm using Mac OS X, and I built Emacs from the current CVS sources, using `./configure --with-ns`.

What's going on here, and/or how I can fix it?

Comment: I use Emacs 23 and `php-mode` shipped with Emacs Starter Kit (also v1.5.0). It works. You may have some other modes in your .emacs that effects `php-mode`.

Comment: I've changed my .emacs to just "(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp") (require 'php-mode)", and the problem persists.

Comment: Can you put your dotemacs somewhere online?

Comment: As stated above, the problem occurs when my .emacs contains only these two lines:

    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp")
    (require 'php-mode)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when trying to get the csharp-mode up and running. I finally found the solution when digging into the actual Emacs Lisp file for csharp-mode:

```
;;   This code doesn't seem to work when you compile it, then
;;   load/require in the Emacs file. You will get an error (error
;;   "`c-lang-defconst' must be used in a file") which happens because
;;   cc-mode doesn't think it is in a buffer while loading directly
;;   from the init. However, if you call it based on a file extension,
;;   it works properly. Interestingly enough, this doesn't happen if
;;   you don't byte-compile cc-mode.
```

So, the quick and dirty fix to put in your .emacs is to auto load on extension and not put `(require 'php-mode)` or `(load "php-mode")` in there. Without further ado,

```
(autoload 'php-mode "php-mode" "Major mode for editing php code." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php$" . php-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.inc$" . php-mode))
```

I hope this helps! Now I just need to get the PHP/HTML mode switching stuff working. Wish me luck.

Comment: Late to the party, but thanks so much for this.  I don't have a problem on Linux, but on Windows, I was getting this same error, since nxhtml autoloads a lot of stuff on its own.  I deleted my cc-*.elc files, and the errors went away.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem with proto-mode (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/editors/protobuf-mode.el), and this fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with http://mewde.googlecode.com/files/php-mode-new.el.